# Realizei uma edição de uma pergunta e não foi para análise

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Realizei uma edição em uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109279/subir-aplicacao-para-servidor-glassfis) e enviei para ser analisada por um especializa, conforme mensagem abaixo:

> Obrigado por sua edição!
>   Esta edição será visível apenas para você até que seja analisada por um especialista.

Acessando a pergunta e o [histórico de revisões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/109279/revisions), não aparece minha sugestão.

Nota-se que ouve uma alteração posterior a minha edição, segundos, e com usuário com pontuação maior que 2000, isso dá o [privilegio de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) ao mesmo.

Minha dúvida seria, se estou editando e um outro usuário sugere uma edição aparece uma mensagem no superior da página informando isso, para usuários com o [privilegio de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) também aparece ou não?

Outra coisa, acredito que a edição que realizei está bem mais completa da realizada.

Comment: [Esta edição conflitou com uma edição anterior.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/52826)

Comment: @Math, a rejeição ocorreu de forma automática? E por que, "Esta edição conflitou com uma edição anterior."

Comment: Sim, foi de forma automática. Sobre a sua dúvida: acho que o usuário que está editando não recebe a notificação de que apareceu uma sugestão enquanto ele já editava.

Comment: To tentando formular uma resposta mas não tenho certeza de alguns comportamentos do mecanismo, mas para o caso em específico, eu acho que o usuário que fez uma edição que sobrepôs a sua não tinha conhecimento da sua sugestão. E se a pessoa ainda não tiver começado a editar e já tiver alguma sugestão, não é possível que ela edite e ignore a sugestão, tem que primeiro avaliar a sugestão para depois se quiser editar a pergunta.

Comment: Então @Math, já recebi a notificação de que uma **Edição** já foi realizada, o que eu faço, é parar de editar, ir na pergunta e ver como ficou. Então decido em parar de editar ou editar em cima da edição, caso ache necessário.

Comment: Certeza que você recebeu uma notificação de **sugestão** de edição? Ou recebeu uma notificação de **edição**? Eu acho que é o segundo caso. Eu tenho certeza que edições emitem essa notificação para quem está editando, e acho que novas sugestões não emitem essa notificação, é essa a parte que eu tenho dúvida, e é bem difícil de simular um teste assim para ter certeza.

Comment: @Math essa notificação(barra laranja no topo) ai aparece quando estamos ainda editando e alguém já fez uma edição e foi aprovada ou o próprio OP editou a pergunta.

Comment: @David se você receber a notificação(laranja) e continuar, tudo que a outra edição modificou será perdido e a sua vai passar a valer(isso não quer dizer que não haverá histórico de revisão de ambas).

Comment: @DiegoFelipe pela minha pontuação não tenho o privilegio de edição, posso sugerir, então como o outro usuário tem e estava editando, será que ele recebeu a notificação que ouve uma sugestão? O que você disse explica o motivo que minha sugestão foi rejeitada.

Comment: @David isso eu não sei informar também, mas creio que não seja, pois uma sugestão ainda não é uma edição concretizada, e questionei uma vez um user +2000 e ele disse que não recebe aviso.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe coloca como resposta, assim efetivo que minha dúvida foi resolvida e de possíveis usuários que possa acontecer.

Comment: Como se trata de uma peculiaridade de funcionamento, acho legal o @Gabe, ou ao menos os moderadores, conseguirem uma explicação mais detalhada. Tenho impressão de ter visto esse assunto sair mais de uma vez (comments e/ou chat) e não lembro de explicação oficial.

Answer (score 5):

Nós não bloqueamos o post quando alguém começa a editar, então é possível que múltiplas pessoas editem um post ao mesmo tempo, sem se dar conta. Só temos como saber se isso aconteceu depois que as edições são enviadas. Nesse caso o sistema se comporta de maneiras diferentes, dependendo se as edições foram *sugeridas* ou feitas por alguém com [privilégio de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

- Uma edição com privilégio vai sobrescrever outra edição se ela for mais *extensa* (fez mais alterações no post) do que uma edição anterior, mas a anterior é mantida no histórico de revisões. Se a edição posterior for *menos extensa*, então ela será bloqueada e o autor notificado.
- Uma edição privilegiada sempre vai sobrescrever, e rejeitar, uma edição sujerida pendente. Isso pode ser feito explicitamente por um revisor (escolhendo "rejeitar e editar") ou implicitamente pelo sistema (se um editor enviou sua edição depois de uma sugestão ser feita).

Quanto à sugestões *aprovadas*, elas tem o mesmo comportamento de edições privilegiadas na hora de resolver conflitos (a edição conflitante vai ser rejeitada se for menos extensa). Além disso, editores são notificados se alguém enviar uma edição potencialmente conflitante enquanto eles ainda estão editando, mas não serão notificados de conflitos que acontecerem depois do envio da sua edição.

<sub>*Thanks to Gabe for the translation!*

*All blame to Gabe for any errors in the translation!*</sub>